# Flask approute not found

Tags: python, flask

i tried to define @approute in flask but when i go to 127.0.0.1:5000/home i get 404 Requested URL was not found.

My code is like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run()
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'dbname'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "index page"

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

And in flaskproject/templates/home.html i have only:

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: is your app running on port 5000? From what you show, it looks like it should work. Please try to narrow down the problem and give more information.

Comment: Several things are possible (e.g., calling `app.run()` before the `@app.route), but we'll need to see more code to help you.

Comment: Yes my app is running on 5000 i can even see traffic in console as i try to access the route and i am starting flask app with "flask run --host 0.0.0.0" command.

Comment: Move the line `app.run()` to the end of the file. Or, better even, you can remove it entirely if you're using the flask CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.run()
```

Is a blocking call. All the statements written below that won't be executed. I don't know how flask/python handles the methods defined below. But the most probable mistake is, that after `app.run()` was called, nothing else will be executed. So try it like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'dbname'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def index:
    return "index page"


@app.route('/home')
def home:
    return render_template("home.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: One small problem. You need to define `app` before you can use `@app.route`

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake the first time I posted, just edited that right after. Look again.